# More Fingerprint IDs in r307 Finger Print sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I am using **PyFingerprint** python library. It's finerprintID storage capacity is 1000. How can store more than 1000 fingerprint IDs ?

my fingerprint sensor is **r307**

Comment: The module is not Pi specific. I would ask the dev at https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint/issues

Comment: do some research .... read the r307 datasheet .... if you still have a question, then please update your post

Comment: thanx for your answers Dirk and jsotola. But i am flexible to use it with Arduino. U can answer me assuming that i am using arduino :)